# Selecting value in dropdown with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I am trying to get a hook on a select and set the selected option. I am struggling to do this because my drop down is generated in a loop so the id changes.

Normally I would do something like this

`select product_template.name, :from => "product_product_template_id`

What if the ID can change

`e.g. product_product_presentations_attributes_0_presentation_id`

Is there a way to leverage the select function and specify a css selector?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there multiple elements where the id only differs by the value - ie is there `product_product_presentations_attributes_0_presentation_id` and `product_product_presentations_attributes_1_presentation_id`?

Comment: Yes. Reading your comment makes me think I could just use find and a css selector and filter out items till I get the item I want. From that I can get the ID and use that in the ```select``` method. Don't know why I didn't think of that before, but it would be nice if you could pass in a css selector directly into the :from option or perhaps another option.

Answer (score 0):

`select` also accepts `label` (as in the actual `<label>` text for that select) and `name` attributes for the `:from` option, so if those are not generated / changed all the time, you can use them for a less brittle test.

If that doesn't cut it, you can add a unique CSS class to your select and then select a specific option with something like:

`find("select.new_css_class").find("option[value='THE OPTION VALUE YOU WANT']").select_option`